# How is file content sent to browser after HTTP response returns?

Tags: http, browser, download

When initiating a file download from the browser, I would send the server a request for the file. I know that the server then returns a response with content-type either as `attachment` or `application/octect-stream`. This lets the browser know that it should initiate the file download.

What I want to know is, how is the file data sent from the server to the client once the response has already be returned? Does it use a different protocol than http? is it always streamed from the server? or is the full file content sent in the response and then the browser just downloads it onto the client machine without maintaining a connection to the remote server?

Is there a way to know when this process has finished from either the server or the client?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the the file being downloaded **is included** in the response. Response headers are followed by an empty line and then you have actual file data.